# In MVC, how can I tell if page is printing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, printing

I'm writing an MVC application. The result page shows a table with 10 columns. However, when the user hits the print button in the browser or hits Ctrl-P, I want two of the columns to disappear (they're just hyperlinks). Is there an easy way to know this is happening so I can hide or remove the display of those columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use CSS for this.  You can specify some styles that only apply when someone is printing using `@media print`.

One thing I tend to do is add the following style to my style sheet

```
@media print {
    .dont-print {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

Then, anything you don't want to show up when the user prints the page, you give a class "dont-print".

Comment: As much as I hate `!important`, this really is the best solution! Edit: What he's saying here is that this has NOTHING to do with .NET, just some core web stuff.

Comment: I had tried a couple of other css things, but I think this is a great answer. I'll give this one a shot. Simple and direct.

Answer (score 0):

Use a CSS file that defines classes that are applied during print.

Media Types are your friend here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp